# invoke node.js server-side service in angularjs. getting following error. Error: [$injector:nomod] Module ‘angularjsNodejsTutorial’ is not available

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

This is the error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularjsNodejsTutorial due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module ‘angularjsNodejsTutorial’ is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.” exception. from browser or postman when I hit localhost:3000/dirPath then I get the data back but not through this html file.

//here are the files: index.html, app.js(angularjs) and index.js(node)

//index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="angularjsNodejsTutorial">
    <head>
        <title>Integrating AngularJS with NodeJS</title>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <div ng-controller="myController">

        <ul >
            <li> The Files Are: {{data}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="../public/javascripts/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

//(AngularJS Client-Side)app.js

```
var app = angular.module('angularjsNodejsTutorial',['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [];
    var request = $http.get('/dirPath');
    request.success(function(data) {
        console.print("The files from this directory are:", data);

        $scope.data = data;
    });
    request.error(function(data){
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
});
```

//Server-side node.js index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'index.html'));
});

router.get("/dirPath", function(req, res) {
  var fs = require("fs");

  var dir = '/Users/swapnil/Documents/Test';

  fileList = [];
  var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  for(var i in files){
    if (!files.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    var name = dir+'/'+files[i];
    if (!fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
      fileList.push(name);
    }
  }
  return res.send(fileList);

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: //Client-side(AngularJS) App.js file

var app = angular.module('angularjsNodejsTutorial',['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [];
    var request = $http.get('http://localhost:3000/dirPath');
    request.success(function(data) {
        console.print("The files from this directory are:", data);

        $scope.data = data;
    });
    request.error(function(data){
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
});

Comment: Show us your code, not only the error. How are we expected to help if we can't see what you did wrong???

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add your code to your question (properly formatted). Also please crop your image and insert it directly to the post (if it's really needed). It is considered as polite to keep necessity of visiting other websites when reading a question to minimum.

Comment: Thanks Kevin B, Alon Eitan and YakovL for your feedback. I thought I already added the respective code files. I am pretty new to angular-node and also to the stackoverflow. This is my first question here. Apologies for the inconveniences if any.

Comment: Try to remove the second `<script src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>` (The line before `</body>`)

Comment: @Alon Eitan, Nope it didn't work. I did debug the controller(app.js) on the browser console and found out that when it hit the var request $http.get('dirPath'), it doesn't return any data object back. its null. with this error on 'data' 

"<!doctype html><title>404 Not Found</title><h1 style="text-align: center">404 Not Found</h1><hr/><p style="text-align: center">WebStorm 2016.1.3</p>"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over thinking your route process, this will do the basics:

```
function config ($routeProvider, _) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/Order', {
        templateUrl: '../modern/sections/views/view.html',
        controller: 'Controller as ctrl',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
        resolve: {
            data: function(Factory){
                var view = window.location.href.match(/OrderID=(.*)#/) || 'undefined';

                if(Id === 'undefined'){
                    return Factory.createOrder();
                }else{
                    return Factory.currentOrder(OrderId[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}
```

FYI: Resolve calls Factories where i have services setup to get my API data.

Sorry if this is not direct, i copied this over from a current working project i have.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by exposing the server side functionality as a RESTful API instead of node and modified my controller by adding appropriate header info for content type and implemented CORS filter on the server side.

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                // CORS "pre-flight" request
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        "X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type, Accept");

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Thanks everyone for taking time to look at my issue and offering help. Appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Check your modules and make sure they are being loaded appropriately. It's a very common error when you start out. Check your html file and make sure all the modules names are spelled correctly.

If your modules are sharing logic it's common to accidentally miss spell the module name. This case I normally copy and past it over.

Also look at your logic behind the module and make sure you are declaring it properly.

Comment: Thanks Keeano. Yeah I checked it. I have also added the html and js files here in a hope that someone can point out the mistake. thanks again.

Comment: Take the complexity out of your router, especially if your new to angularjs. This can be done way better...Once i get off my mobile i will show you a simple routes file that delivers a home page